# Android action bar not showing up when extending a class that extends the activity class

Tags: java, android, abstract-class, subclass

I have an abstract class GenericConfiguration:

```
public abstract class GenericConfiguration extends Activity{
    //Overrides onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) and
    //public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
}
```

Then I have two subclasses TemperatureConfiguration and LightingConfiguration which look like this:

```
public class TemperatureConfiguration extends GenericConfiguration{
    //Overrides onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
}
```

When I run the subclass activities they do not display the menu defined in the GenericConfiguration. I would think that since they inherit the onOptionsItemSelected and onCreateOptionsMenu methods that they should no? What am I doing wrong? This is my first time ever writing an and abstract class and subclassing.

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Comment: Do the classes that extend `GenericConfiguration` override `onCreateOptionsMenu()`?

Comment: @emerssso no they dont but shouldnt they inherit that method from GenericConfiguration?

Comment: Try extending GenericConfiguration with ActionbarActivity instead of Activity and check.

Comment: It should, unless you override in the child class and don't call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu()` in the override. ;)

Comment: @rizz86 that was the problem thanks!